# Python3とBeautifulsoup4を使ったHTMLのパースについて

Tags: python, html, python3, web-scraping

```
<h1>タイトル</h1>
<h2>サブタイトル1<h2>
<ul>
<li>本文</li>
<li>本文</li>
...
</ul>
<h3>サブサブタイトル<h3>
<ul>
<li>本文</li>
<li>本文</li>
...
</ul>
<h2>サブタイトル2<h2>
...
<h2>サブタイトル3<h2>
...
```

というような構造のHTMLからタイトル->サブタイトル->サブサブタイトルと指定した範囲内で本文を取得するパースをしたいのですがどのようにすればいいでしょうか。

```
title_lv1 = soup.findAll('h1')
    for title1 in title_lv1:
        if title1.text == sys.argv[1]:
            print(title1.findAll('h2')
```

というようにすると空のリストが出力されてしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

質問で提示されたhtmlには閉じられていないタグが含まれますが、`<h2>...</h2>`のようにタグが閉じられているhtmlを用いる前提で記述します。

提示されたhtmlは入れ子になっていないので、findAllを使って`h1`の中にある`h2`は取得できません。
下記のような構造ならば`title1.findAll('h2')`で`h2`が取得できます。

```
<h1>
    <h2>入れ子!</h2>
</h1>
```

今回のような並列構造では、`find_next_sibling`を使って条件付きで隣のタグを取得する必要があります。
下記のようなコードで、目的の本文を取得できそうです。

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html'), 'html.parser')
#textで指定する各タイトルは、変数やコマンドライン引数に書き換えてください
h3 = soup.find('h1', text='タイトル').find_next_sibling('h2', text='サブタイトル').find_next_sibling('h3', text='サブサブタイトル')
ul = h3.find_next_sibling('ul')
for li in ul.findAll('li'):
  print(li.text)
```

ただし上記のコードは`find_next_sibling`で、見つかったタグの下にあるタグをすべて見つけるため、下記のような問題が発生する可能性があります。
タグが必ず存在する前提ならば問題ありませんが、そうでなければ`find_next_sibling`にtextの条件を追加せず、for文などを使って範囲の洗い出しをするよう改修してください。

```
<h1>タイトル</h1>
<h2>サブタイトル</h2>
<!--サブサブタイトルがない-->
<h2>サブタイトル2</h2>
<h3>サブサブタイトル</h3> <!--←サンプルコードのNextSiblingでサブタイトル2の下にスキップしてしまう-->
```